# using c++ in xcode / objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode3.2

So I'm trying to use C++ inside my ios project.

After I make a new project (all default settings, fresh install of xcode), I create a `Question.h` and a `Question.mm` file, like this:

```
Question.h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Question {
public:
   string text;
};


Question.mm

#include "Question.h"
```

it screams with errors like: `Iostream: No such file or directory`

using Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Iostream in the error message begins with a capital letter - have you done that in any of your code?

Comment: Does is show the same error if you rename Question.mm -> Question.cpp?

Comment: its with capital letter in the Build Results window, but in the code it's `iostream`. One more thing: if I move all the code from the `h` file to the `mm` file it does build successfully

Comment: @Alex, changing the extension has the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is that you're including `Question.h` in a non-C++ file, for instance perhaps your AppDelegate is a .m file and you're trying to include `Question.h` there.

There are two solutions. First, you can make everything Objective-C++ (renaming all .m files to .mm). Historically I've found that to be extremely inconvenient because both Xcode and gdb have always had a lot of trouble with ObjC++ and you can get a lot of confusion (the dreaded "no this pointer" and "unknown language for stack frame" errors in gdb). I haven't done enough work with the latest versions of Xcode and gdb to determine if this is still a problem, but I suspect it is since gdb hasn't gotten a lot of work. Also, ObjC++ is slower to compile.

The other option is to [wrap up your C++ into ObjC](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486) so that you can include it freely into pure ObjC portions of the code. This is the approach I usually take. ObjC++ is a bit of a mess of a language IMO, and I believe it's better to keep ObjC (.m) and C++ (.cpp) pure and separate with a thin layer of ObjC++ (.mm) to glue them together.

Comment: I still can't believe how blind I am. I WAS including Question.h in appDelegate. The funny thing is that I did a Project Search for Question.h and no result showed..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your main.m file isn't importing your AppDelegate file.  It may be using it like this:

`NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])`

but instead you can just do this:

`@"AppDelegate"`

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `Question.mm` to `Question.cpp` as xcode decides which compiler to use based on the extension.

Comment: that doesn't fix it. besides, I have another project that i created some time ago, which uses h/mm files and they do compile successfully. can't point the difference between them tho..

Comment: As a side note: if you *can* rename Question.mm to Question.cpp, you should. Pure C++ is easier to manage and faster to compile than Objective-C++. If you need access to just a couple of Cocoa-like things (like reading an NSArray), you can also use Core Foundation, which is a pure-C interface to many of the Cocoa data structures. You can include that in C++ without switching to Objective-C++. Obviously there are some places that ObjC++ is required, but when you don't need it, it's nice to avoid.